# How to split a text dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, gsap

I have a React component and I need to triger an animation, but i want to recieve a long text and depending on the width of the container (500px or 300px) and on the size of the text I'll have more or less lines of text.

How can I split the text in order to get an array of texts, but dynamically? Because the text comes from the API and the length is variable.

I need to use a GSAP animation for text reveal in each

but that's the easy part, I think.

This is the code:

```
const Test = () => {
  const paragraphRef = useRef(null);
  const text = "a really long text, like 500 words"
  useEffect(() => {
    // get the values of the ref
  },[])

  return (
    <div>

      <div className='h-screen'>
        <div className='w-[300px] md:w-[500px] mx-auto' ref={paragraphRef}>
            {
              /**
               * Here i want to map an array each line like: allTheLines.map((text) => <p className="text-lg md:text-xl">{text}</p>)
               */
            }
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Comment: I think the reason you're having trouble is the same reason anyone here might struggle to answer.  When you say you want the text split dynamically, what exactly do you mean? I feel like you are overcomplicating something that can probably just be handled with CSS.

Comment: I'm trying to do this: https://youtu.be/4xZqN80Tp7k?t=480 but in the video he's using 3 divs one for each line, but i need to split the text in that i receive from the backend in order to implement this animation. Also i need to make it responsive.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to know how to split your string called `text` into an array of _lines_.  Presumably you just need to `.split` that string with a newline character `\n` as the delimiter.  If the original text isn't preformatted into lines, then I would *not* break it into `p` elements manually, but rather allow CSS to perform wrapping using one of the existing `word-wrap` strategies.

Comment: But that wouldn't allow me to execute the animation line by line, it would be sentence by sentence. Or i'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this?

```
const numberOfWordsPerItem = 6;

const string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit, bibendum dis habitasse facilisi rhoncus commodo pretium, dui mus placerat suspendisse pulvinar congue.";

const words = string.split(' ');
const groups = [];

for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i += numberOfWordsPerItem) {
  groups.push(words.slice(i, i + numberOfWordsPerItem).join(' '));
}

console.log(groups);
```

Here a string is packed into an array in 6-word blocks.

Comment: But if I have a very long sentence and the words are too long, 2 things would happen or the text would go out of the container or a new line would be created and I would have blank spaces inside the line

Comment: This is a difficult task, since you always have to keep an eye on the screen dimensions.
You could still calculate the font size based on the dimensions of the text area and the word lengths (number of letters and spaces).

Comment: Yes, I'm trying a few things but allways need a new value to look at

Comment: Maybe dynamically choosing the number of words in each word block in the array would work so that the text always gets roughly the same length.

Have a look here: https://codepen.io/herr_toto/pen/YzJpxwW